# My django form is not sending the values correctly to my responses page

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

Im invested on solving the code, theres still some things missing, i took a print

[image]

the visual part of the pages seem fine, but theres something wrong with how im sending the values and I cant find what, im very distracted though and just started to learn Django, id be glad if someone could help me.

views.py

```
imports

def form_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ParticipantResponseForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            response = form.save(commit=False)

            # Check if absences_count is not empty before saving
            absences_count_value = form.cleaned_data['absences_count']
            response.absences_count = int(absences_count_value) if absences_count_value else 0

            response.save()

            # Add a success message
            messages.success(request, 'Form submitted successfully!')

            # Print form data for debugging
            print(form.cleaned_data)

            # Redirect to responses page
            return redirect('show_responses')
    else:
        form = ParticipantResponseForm()

    return render(request, '    form.html', {'form': form})


def show_responses(request):
    responses = ParticipantResponse.objects.all()
    print(responses)
    return render(request, 'responses.html', {'responses': responses})
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from .choices import PARTICIPANT_DISABILITY_CHOICES
class Disability(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class ParticipantResponse(models.Model):
    participant_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    birth_date = models.DateField()
    gender_choices = [
    ('male', 'Masculino'),
    ('female', 'Feminino'),
    ]

    PARTICIPANT_DISABILITY_CHOICES = [
    #choices
]


    gender = models.CharField(max_length=6, choices=gender_choices)
    participant_disability = models.CharField(max_length=255, choices=PARTICIPANT_DISABILITY_CHOICES, default='')
    clinical_diagnosis = models.TextField()
    functional_profile = models.TextField()
    participation_modalities = models.TextField()
    participation_observations = models.TextField()
    attendance_frequency = models.IntegerField()
    attended_dates = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    absences_count = models.IntegerField()
    absent_dates = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    school_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    additional_observations = models.TextField()
    dropout_list = models.TextField(blank=True)
    dropout_reason = models.TextField(blank=True)
    responding_teacher_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"Response for {self.participant_name}"
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .choices import PARTICIPANT_DISABILITY_CHOICES
from .models import ParticipantResponse, Disability

class ParticipantResponseForm(forms.ModelForm):

    PARTICIPANT_DISABILITY_CHOICES = [(str(disability.id), disability.name) for disability in Disability.objects.all()]
    
    ATTENDANCE_CHOICES = [
        ('', 'Escolha'),
        (0, 'Não frequentou o mês todo'),
        *[(i, str(i)) for i in range(1, 26)],
    ]

    ABSENCES_CHOICES = [
        ('', 'Escolha'),
        *[(str(i), str(i)) for i in range(0, 26)],
    ]

    PARTICIPATION_MODALITIES_CHOICES = [
        ('', 'Escolha'),
        ('Desenvolvimento Motor - Polo artex', 'Desenvolvimento Motor - Polo artex'),
        ('Desenvolvimento Motor - Polo ASMOSABE', 'Desenvolvimento Motor - Polo ASMOSABE'),
        ('Desenvolvimento Motor - Polo Vasto Verde', 'Desenvolvimento Motor - Polo Vasto Verde'),
        ('Equitação Adaptada', 'Equitação Adaptada'),
        ('Ginástica Artística Adaptada - Polo ABLUGO', 'Ginástica Artística Adaptada - Polo ABLUGO'),
        ('Iniciação rendimento Bocha Paralímpica', 'Iniciação rendimento Bocha Paralímpica'),
        ('Iniciação rendimento Goalball', 'Iniciação rendimento Goalball'),
        ('Iniciação rendimento Para-Atletismo', 'Iniciação rendimento Para-Atletismo'),
        ('Iniciação rendimento Para-Natação', 'Iniciação rendimento Para-Natação'),
        ('Iniciação rendimento Tênis de Mesa Paralímpico', 'Iniciação rendimento Tênis de Mesa Paralímpico'),
        ('Para-Natação Escolar - Sede', 'Para-Natação Escolar - Sede'),
        ('EBM Anita Garibaldi', 'EBM Anita Garibaldi'),
        ('EBM Adelaide Starke', 'EBM Adelaide Starke'),
        ('EBM Leoberto Leal', 'EBM Leoberto Leal'),
        ('EBM Visconde de Taunay', 'EBM Visconde de Taunay'),
        ('EBM Felipe Schmidt', 'EBM Felipe Schmidt'),
        ('EBM Lucio Esteves', 'EBM Lucio Esteves'),
        ('EBM João Joaquim Fronza', 'EBM João Joaquim Fronza'),
        ('EBM Wilheim Theodor Schurmann', 'EBM Wilheim Theodor Schurmann'),
        ('EBM Lauro Muller', 'EBM Lauro Muller'),
        ('Iniciação rendimento Futebol PC', 'Iniciação rendimento Futebol PC'),
        ('Iniciação rendimento Futebol DI', 'Iniciação rendimento Futebol DI'),
        # Add more options as needed
    ]
    
    GENDER_CHOICES = [
        ('male', 'Male'),
        ('female', 'Female'),
    ]

    participant_name = forms.CharField(
        required=True,
        label='1 - Nome do participante'
    )

    birth_date = forms.DateField(
        required=True,
        label='2 - Data de nascimento'
    )

    gender = forms.ChoiceField(
        choices=GENDER_CHOICES,
        required=True,
        widget=forms.RadioSelect,
        label='3 - Sexo do participante'
    )  

    participant_disability = forms.MultipleChoiceField(
        choices=PARTICIPANT_DISABILITY_CHOICES,
        widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
        required=True,
        label='4 - Deficiência do Participante'
    )

    clinical_diagnosis = forms.CharField(
        required=True,
        label='5 - Qual seu diagnóstico clínico?'
    )

    functional_profile = forms.CharField(
        required=True,
        label='6 - Perfil funcional da Deficiência e do participante'
    )

    participation_modalities = forms.ChoiceField(
        choices=PARTICIPATION_MODALITIES_CHOICES,
        required=True,
        label='7 - Participa em qual modalidade?'
    )

    participation_observations = forms.CharField(
        required=False,
        label='8 - Observações da participação do participante neste mês.'
    )

    attendance_frequency = forms.ChoiceField(
        choices=ATTENDANCE_CHOICES,
        required=True,
        label='9 - Quantas vezes o participante frequentou nas aulas neste mês?'
    )

    attended_dates = forms.CharField(
        required=True,
        label='10 - Quais as datas frequentou neste mês: (Exemplo 2,4,6...).'
    )

    absences_count = forms.ChoiceField(
        choices=ABSENCES_CHOICES,
        required=False,
        label='11 - Número de faltas neste mês?'
    )

    absent_dates = forms.CharField(
        required=False,
        label='12 - Quais as datas que não frequentou este mês: (Exemplo 10,12,14...).'
    )

    school_name = forms.CharField(
        required=True,
        label='13 - Nome da Escola que o participante estuda.'
    )

    additional_observations = forms.CharField(
        required=False,
        label='14 - Observações:'
    )

    dropout_list = forms.CharField(
        required=False,
        label='15 - Listar participante desistente:'
    )

    dropout_reason = forms.CharField(
        required=False,
        label='16 - Motivo da desistência:'
    )

    responding_teacher_name = forms.CharField(
        required=True,
        label='17 - Nome do professor que respondeu'
    )

    class Meta:
        model = ParticipantResponse
        exclude = []
        fields = '__all__'
        widgets = {
            'birth_date': forms.DateInput(attrs={'type': 'date', 'class': 'w3-input', 'id': 'id_birth_date'}),
        }
    
    def clean_participant_disability(self):
        participant_disability = self.cleaned_data['participant_disability']
        if not participant_disability:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Select at least one disability.")
        return participant_disability



    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ParticipantResponseForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['participant_disability'].choices = PARTICIPANT_DISABILITY_CHOICES
```

form.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Relatório Paradesporto Escolar - Fevereiro 2023</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet"
        href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css">
</head>

<body>
    <script>
        function toggleDarkMode() {
            var body = document.body;

            // Toggle the 'dark-mode' class on the body
            body.classList.toggle('dark-mode');

        }
    </script>
    <button class="btn-DarkMode" onclick="toggleDarkMode()"
        style="position: fixed; top: 20px; right: 20px; cursor: pointer; font-size: 20px;"></button>

    <div class="container">
        <section>
            <ul class="linha"></ul>
            <h1>Relatório Paradesporto Escolar - Fevereiro 2023</h1>
            <ul>Relatório de frequência das aulas presenciais. <br></ul>
            <ul>
                <span>* Indica pergunta obrigatória</span>
            </ul>
        </section>
        {% if messages %}
        <ul class="messages">
            {% for message in messages %}
            <li{% if message.tags %} class="{{ message.tags }}" {% endif %}>{{ message }}</li>
                {% endfor %}
        </ul>
        {% endif %}


        <form method="post" class="needs-validation" novalidate id="reportForm">
            {% csrf_token %}

            <section>
                <label for="{{ form.participant_name.id_for_label }}">1 - Nome do participante: (Completo, sem
                    abreviaturas).
                    <span>*</span>
                </label>
                <input type="text" class="w3-input" name="{{ form.participant_name.name }}" required
                    placeholder="Insira sua resposta">
            </section>

            <section>
                <label for="{{ form.birth_date.id_for_label }}">2 - Data de nascimento:
                    <span>*</span>
                </label>
                <input type="date" name="{{ form.birth_date.name }}" id="{{ form.birth_date.id }}"
                    value="{{ form.birth_date.value }}" class="w3-input" required>
            </section>

            <section>
                <label>3 - Sexo do participante: <span>*</span></label>
                <div class="radio-group w3-container">
                    {% for radio in form.gender %}
                    <label class="form-check">
                        {{ radio.tag }}
                        {{ radio.choice_label }}
                    </label>
                    {% endfor %}
                </div>
            </section>

            <section>
                <label>4 - Deficiência do Participante: <span>*</span></label>
                <div class="checkbox-group w3-container">
                    {% for disability in form.participant_disability %}
                    <div class="form-check">
                        {{ disability }}
                    </div>
                    {% endfor %}
                </div>
            </section>

            <section>
                <label for="{{ form.clinical_diagnosis.id_for_label }}">5 - Qual seu diagnóstico clínico?
                    <span>*</span>
                </label>
                <input type="text" class="w3-input" name="{{ form.clinical_diagnosis.name }}" required
                    placeholder="Insira sua resposta">
            </section>

            <section>
                <label for="{{ form.functional_profile.id_for_label }}">6 - Perfil funcional da Deficiência e do
                    participante:
                    <span>*</span>
                </label>
                <input type="text" class="w3-input" name="{{ form.functional_profile.name }}" required
                    placeholder="Insira sua resposta">


            </section>

            <section>
                <label for="{{ form.participation_modalities.id_for_label }}">7 - Participa em qual modalidade?
                    <span>*</span>
                </label>
                {{ form.participation_modalities }}
            </section>

            <section>
                <label for="{{ form.participation_observations.id_for_label }}">8 - Observações da participação do
                    participante neste mês.</label>
                <input type="text" class="w3-input" name="{{ form.participation_observations.name }}"
                    placeholder="Insira sua resposta">
            </section>

            <section>
                <label for="{{ form.attendance_frequency.id_for_label }}">9 - Quantas vezes o participante frequentou
                    nas
                    aulas neste mês?
                    <span>*</span>
                </label>
                {{ form.attendance_frequency }}
            </section>

            <section>
                <label for="{{ form.attended_dates.id_for_label }}">10 - Quais as datas frequentou neste mês: (Exemplo
                    2,4,6...).
                    <span>*</span>
                </label>
                <input type="text" class="w3-input" name="{{ form.attended_dates.name }}" required
                    placeholder="Insira sua resposta">
            </section>

            <section>
                <label for="{{ form.absences_count.id_for_label }}">11 - Número de faltas neste mês?</label>
                {{ form.absences_count }}
            </section>

            <section>
                <label for="{{ form.absent_dates.id_for_label }}">12 - Quais as datas que não frequentou este mês:
                    (Exemplo
                    10,12,14...).</label>
                <input type="text" class="w3-input" name="{{ form.absent_dates.name }}"
                    placeholder="Insira sua resposta">
            </section>

            <section>
                <label for="{{ form.school_name.id_for_label }}">13 - Nome da Escola que o participante estuda:
                    (Observação:
                    Nome completo da escola, sem abreviaturas). <span>*</span></label>
                <input type="text" class="w3-input" name="{{ form.school_name.name }}" required
                    placeholder="Insira sua resposta">

            </section>

            <section>
                <label for="{{ form.additional_observations.id_for_label }}">14 - Observações:</label>
                <input type="text" class="w3-input" name="{{ form.additional_observations.name }}"
                    placeholder="Insira sua resposta">
            </section>

            <section>
                <label for="{{ form.dropout_list.id_for_label }}">15 - Listar participante desistente:</label>
                <input type="text" class="w3-input" name="{{ form.dropout_list.name }}"
                    placeholder="Insira sua resposta">
            </section>

            <section>
                <label for="{{ form.dropout_reason.id_for_label }}">16 - Motivo da desistência:</label>
                <input type="text" class="w3-input" name="{{ form.dropout_reason.name }}"
                    placeholder="Insira sua resposta">
            </section>

            <section>
                <label for="{{ form.responding_teacher_name.id_for_label }}">17 - Nome do professor que respondeu.
                    <span>*</span>
                </label>
                <input type="text" class="w3-input" name="{{ form.responding_teacher_name.name }}" required
                    placeholder="Insira sua resposta">
            </section>

            <button type="submit" class="w3-btn">Submit</button>{% if form.errors %}
            <button type="button" class="clear-btn" onclick="clearForm()">Clear Form</button>
            <ul class="errorlist">
                {% for field, errors in form.errors.items %}
                <li>{{ field }}:
                    <ul class="errorlist">
                        {% for error in errors %}
                        <li>{{ error }}</li>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </ul>
                </li>
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
            {% endif %}
        </form>
    </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script
        src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>

    <!-- ... (previous code) ... -->

    <script>
        function toggleDarkMode() {
            var body = document.body;
            
            // Toggle the 'dark-mode' class on the body
            body.classList.toggle('dark-mode');
        }

        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
            const form = document.getElementById('reportForm');
            const requiredFields = form.querySelectorAll('[required]');

            form.addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
                let isFormValid = true;

                requiredFields.forEach((field) => {
                    let isEmpty = false;

                    if (field.type === 'checkbox' || field.type === 'radio') {
                        const group = document.getElementsByName(field.name);
                        isEmpty = !Array.from(group).some((radio) => radio.checked);
                    } else {
                        isEmpty = field.value.trim() === '';
                    }

                    const section = field.closest('section');

                    if (isEmpty) {
                        isFormValid = false;
                        section.classList.add('error'); // Add error class

                        const errorMessage = document.createElement('div');
                        errorMessage.className = 'errorlist';
                        errorMessage.innerText = 'Questão obrigatória';

                        const existingError = section.querySelector('.errorlist');
                        if (!existingError) {
                            section.appendChild(errorMessage);
                        }
                    }
                });

                if (!isFormValid) {
                    event.preventDefault();

                    // Find the first section with the 'error' class
                    const firstErrorSection = document.querySelector('section.error');

                    if (firstErrorSection) {
                        // Find the first input element within the error section and set focus
                        const firstErrorInput = firstErrorSection.querySelector('input, select, textarea');
                        if (firstErrorInput) {
                            firstErrorInput.focus();
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

            requiredFields.forEach((field) => {
                field.addEventListener('blur', () => {
                    const isEmpty = (field.type === 'checkbox' || field.type === 'radio')
                        ? !field.checked
                        : field.value.trim() === '';

                    const section = field.closest('section');
                    section.classList.toggle('error', isEmpty); // Toggle error class

                    if (isEmpty && field.type !== 'radio') {
                        const errorMessage = document.createElement('div');
                        errorMessage.className = 'errorlist';
                        errorMessage.innerText = 'Field required';

                        const existingError = section.querySelector('.errorlist');
                        if (!existingError) {
                            section.appendChild(errorMessage);
                        }
                    } else {
                        const existingError = section.querySelector('.errorlist');
                        if (existingError) {
                            existingError.remove();
                        }
                    }
                });

                field.addEventListener('focus', () => {
                    const section = field.closest('section');
                    section.classList.remove('error'); // Remove error class on focus
                });

                field.style.transition = 'border 0.3s ease-in-out';
            });
        });

        function clearForm() {
            const form = document.getElementById('reportForm');
            const inputs = form.querySelectorAll('input, select, textarea');
            let isFormEmpty = true;

            inputs.forEach((input) => {
                if (input.type !== 'submit' && input.type !== 'button' && (input.value || input.checked)) {
                    isFormEmpty = false;
                }
            });

            if (!isFormEmpty) {
                const isConfirmed = confirm("Are you sure you want to clear the form?");

                if (isConfirmed) {
                    inputs.forEach((input) => {
                        if (input.type !== 'submit' && input.type !== 'button') {
                            input.value = '';
                            input.checked = false;
                            input.closest('section').classList.remove('error'); // Remove error class
                        }
                    });
                }
            } else {
                alert("The form is already cleared.");
            }
        }

        function resetFormOnLoad() {
    const form = document.getElementById('reportForm');

    if (form) {
        const inputs = form.querySelectorAll('input, select, textarea');

        inputs.forEach((input) => {
            if (input.type !== 'submit' && input.type !== 'button') {
                input.value = '';
                input.checked = false;
                const section = input.closest('section');
                if (section) {
                    section.classList.remove('error'); // Remove error class
                    const existingError = section.querySelector('.errorlist');
                    if (existingError) {
                        existingError.remove();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
}


        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", resetFormOnLoad);

        window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            e.returnValue = '';
        });
    </script>
  

</body>

</html>
```

I already tried step by step changing the code, I searched online and still nothing, so I had to ask directly for help